# How to center a circle node on the terminal payoff value?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node, istgame

I am trying to draw a "not allowed" (big X) or "crossed out" (circle with slash) sign on some of the leaves as shown below:

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{istgame}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{max}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{min}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
            [circle]{1.2cm}
            %\xtShowTerminalNodes[box node, minimum size = 1cm]
            \def\distFactor{20};
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
            \setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
            \istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
            \istb[blue, ->-] \istb \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$\leq 1$}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
            \istb{}{2} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
            \istb{}{1} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
            \istb{}{0} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(6)(2-2)[min]
            \istb{}{-1} \istb{}{0} \endist
            \draw ([yshift = -5pt]5-2) circle (3mm);
        \end{istgame}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Is there a way to draw either the X or the not allowed circular sign such that it is centered with the number on the leaf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a circle by telling `istgame` that this is to be circle node. And you can define a style for a crossed out circle. (A path picture would draw these on the background, which does not look good for colored texts, so I use `append after command`.) To make this work you then only have to say

```
\istb{}{2}[[ccross]below]
```

instead of

```
\istb{}{2}
```

Result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{istgame}
\tikzset{ccross/.style={circle,draw,yshift=2pt,
append after command={
(\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[thick] (\tikzlastnode.north east)
(\tikzlastnode.south east) edge[thick] (\tikzlastnode.north west)
}}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{istgame}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{max}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{min}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
            [circle]{1.2cm}
            %\xtShowTerminalNodes[box node, minimum size = 1cm]
            \def\distFactor{20};
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
            \setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
            \istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
            \istb[blue, ->-] \istb \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$\leq 1$}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
            \istb{}{2} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
            \istb{}{1} \istb{}{2} \endist
            \istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
            \istb{}{0} \istb{}{2}[[ccross]below] \endist
            \istroot(6)(2-2)[min]
            \istb{}{-1} \istb{}{0} \endist
        \end{istgame}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it. Actually, is there a way that this circle can be drawn such that it iss both centered across the 2 and that the circle’s edge touches the line?

Comment: @Superman Sure, changed that.