# Terminal Leaf Node Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node, istgame

This is a follow up question to [this.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540686/how-to-center-a-circle-node-on-the-terminal-payoff-value/540704#540704)

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{istgame}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{max}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{min}
            [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
            \setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
            [circle]{1.2cm}
            %\xtShowTerminalNodes[box node, minimum size = 1cm]
            \def\distFactor{20};
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
            \setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
            \istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
            \istb[blue, ->-] \istb \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$\leq 1$}
            \istb{0.5}[al] \istb{0.5}[ar] \endist
            \xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
            \istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
            \istb{}{2} \istb{}{5000}[[circle, draw, yshift = 2pt, minimum size = 0.75cm] below] \endist
            \istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
            \istb{}{1} \istb{}{100}[[circle, draw, yshift = 2pt, minimum size = 0.75cm] below] \endist
            \istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
            \istb{}{0} \istb{}{2}[[circle, draw, yshift = 2pt, minimum size = 0.75cm] below] \endist
            \istroot(6)(2-2)[min]
            \istb{}{-1}[[circle, draw, yshift = 2pt, minimum size = 0.75cm] below] \istb{}{0}[[circle, draw, yshift = 2pt, minimum size = 0.75cm] below] \endist
        \end{istgame}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

`minimum size` is part of the solution, but is there any way to align the terminal values with that inside the biggest circle? (Note that the terminal values are listed incorrectly for the sake of getting this output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use `\xtShowEndPoints` followed by `xtShowTerminalNodes`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{istgame}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}    

\begin{istgame}
\setistNewNodeStyle{max}
  [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3]{1.5cm}
\setistNewNodeStyle{min}
  [regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 3, shape border rotate = 180]{1.5cm}
\setistNewNodeStyle{chance}
  [circle]{1.2cm}
\def\distFactor{20};
\xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{4*\distFactor mm}
\setxtarrowtips[blue, thick]
\istroot(0)[max]<center, blue>{1.5}
  \istb[blue, ->-] 
  \istb 
  \endist
\xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{2*\distFactor mm}
\istroot(1)(0-1)[chance]<center, purple>{1.5}
  \istb{0.5}[al] 
  \istb{0.5}[ar] 
  \endist
\istroot(2)(0-2)[chance]<center, purple>{$\leq 1$}
  \istb{0.5}[al] 
  \istb{0.5}[ar] 
  \endist
%% terminal nodes with or without circles (TRICK!!)
\xtShowEndPoints[circle,draw,minimum size=1.1cm] % comes before \xtShowTerminalNodes
\xtShowTerminalNodes[circle,draw=none,minimum size=1.1cm]
\xtdistance{\distFactor mm}{\distFactor mm}
\istroot(3)(1-1)[min]<center, red>{2}
  \istbt{}{2}[center]   %
  \istb{}{5000}[center] 
  \endist
\istroot(4)(1-2)[min]<center, red>{1}
  \istbt{}{1}[center]   %
  \istb{}{100}[center] 
  \endist
\istroot(5)(2-1)[min]<center, red>{0}
  \istbt{}{0}[center]   %
  \istb{}{2}[center] 
  \endist
\istroot(6)(2-2)[min]
  \istb{}{-1}[center] 
  \istb{}{0}[center] 
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```